# MassTransit RequestClient timeout handling

Tags: masstransit

I have tried several scenario to handle timeouts in request, but they dont seem to work.

I have passed the timeout TimeSpan when both creating the request client and/or creating the request. The request does not recive a response during the time span configured, but the task continue executing and seems hanging and no RequestTimeoutException is thrown.

What is the exact solution for handling clients timeout.

**EDIT**

The use case leading to the timeout is when the whole consumer service is down, so the initial request is not consumed at all. Folowing the code exemple of the request. As mentioned, i tried to pass the RequestTimeout also in the client creation. Other than this, it works perfectly when all parts are running.

```
var client = _busControl.CreateRequestClient<CheckRequest>(new Uri($"{rabbitHostUri}/CheckQueue"));
var response = await client.GetResponse<CheckResponse>(checkRequest, timeout: RequestTimeout.After(s: 60)).ConfigureAwait(false);
var checkResponse = response.Message;
```

Comment: Code helps here, but are you awaiting the `GetResponse<T>` call? Is the consumer handling the request calling `RespondAsync`? There are many request/response samples on GitHub, and linked from the documentation.

Comment: That should work, there are dozens of unit tests and samples that work. Is your RabbitMQ bus instance started? Do you have a cancellationToken in that context which can be passed as well? Are you in an ApiController or just a regular main method? Seriously, that looks right and should work. Also, you can use `queue:CheckQueue` instead of passing around the host address.